# How to run yearly optimization problem in monthly format?

Tags: python, pandas, pyomo

I have created a **RTC (Round the clock)** model using **PYOMO** with **solar, wind, and battery** as the main component and **lost_load(Shortfall)**. It's a simple model where these three main sources of energy try to fulfill the demand of **100MW** throughout the year for which they get revenue according to **PPA** ( which is **10 INR/kWh**). And if they fail to do so there is a penalty (**5 INR/kWh**). This model is running on **15min intervals** for a year, so there are a total of **35040 instances**. I want to run this model monthly. It should be something like the model should try to fulfill monthly demand and if the model is not able to fulfill **90% of the total monthly demand** then a shortfall penalty would get applied to it. My Approach :

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pyomo.environ import *


total_instances = 35040
np.random.seed(total_instances)
load_profile = np.array([100]*total_instances)
solar_profile = np.random.rand(total_instances)
wind_profile = np.random.rand(total_instances)

DFR = 0.9
interval_freq = 15
solar_capacity = 120
wind_capacity = 140
power = 50
energy = 200
round_trip_eff = 0.8
PPA = 10
shortfall_penalty = 15
excess_revenue_rate = 0.5 * PPA

model = ConcreteModel()
model.m_index = Set(initialize=list(range(len(load_profile))))

# variable
model.grid = Var(model.m_index, domain=NonNegativeReals)

# storage
# variable
model.storage_power = Param(initialize=power)
model.storage_energy = Param(initialize=energy)
model.chargeEff = Param(initialize=np.sqrt(round_trip_eff))
model.dchargeEff = Param(initialize=np.sqrt(round_trip_eff))
model.e_in = Var(model.m_index, domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.e_out = Var(model.m_index, domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.soc = Var(model.m_index, domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.ein_eout_lmt = Var(model.m_index, domain=Binary)

#  Solar variable
model.solar_capacity = Param(initialize=solar_capacity)
model.solar_use = Var(model.m_index, domain=NonNegativeReals)

#  Wind variables
model.wind_capacity = Param(initialize=wind_capacity)
model.wind_use = Var(model.m_index, domain=NonNegativeReals)

# Solar profile
model.solar_avl = Param(model.m_index, initialize=dict(zip(model.m_index, solar_profile * solar_capacity * interval_freq / 60.0)))

# Wind profile
model.wind_avl = Param(model.m_index, initialize=dict(zip(model.m_index, wind_profile * wind_capacity * interval_freq / 60.0)))

# Load profile
model.load_profile = Param(model.m_index, initialize=dict(zip(model.m_index, load_profile * interval_freq / 60.0)))

model.lost_load = Var(model.m_index, domain=NonNegativeReals)


# Objective function
def revenue(model):
    total_revenue = sum(
        (model.solar_use[m] + model.wind_use[m] + model.e_out[m] - model.e_in[m]) * PPA
        for m in model.m_index
    )
    total_penalty = sum(
        model.lost_load[m] * -shortfall_penalty
        for m in model.m_index
    )

    total_cost = total_revenue + total_penalty

    return total_cost


model.obj = Objective(rule=revenue, sense=maximize)


def energy_balance1(model, m):
    return model.grid[m] == model.solar_use[m] + model.wind_use[m] + model.e_out[m] - model.e_in[m] + model.lost_load[m]


model.energy_balance1 = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=energy_balance1)


def grid_limit(model, m):
    return model.grid[m] >= model.load_profile[m]


model.grid_limit = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=grid_limit)


def max_solar_gen(model, m):
    eq = model.solar_use[m] <= model.solar_avl[m]
    return eq


model.max_solar_gen = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=max_solar_gen)


def max_wind_gen(model, m):
    eq = model.wind_use[m] <= model.wind_avl[m]
    return eq


model.max_wind_gen = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=max_wind_gen)


# Charging and discharging controller
def ein_limit1(model, m):
    eq = model.e_in[m] + (1 - model.ein_eout_lmt[m]) * 1000000 >= 0

    return eq


model.ein_limit1 = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=ein_limit1)


def eout_limit1(model, m):
    eq = model.e_out[m] + (1 - model.ein_eout_lmt[m]) * -1000000 <= 0
    return eq


model.eout_limit1 = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=eout_limit1)


def ein_limit2(model, m):
    eq = model.e_out[m] + (model.ein_eout_lmt[m]) * 1000000 >= 0
    return eq


model.ein_limit2 = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=ein_limit2)


def eout_limit2(model, m):
    eq = model.e_in[m] + (model.ein_eout_lmt[m]) * -1000000 <= 0
    return eq


model.eout_limit2 = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=eout_limit2)


# max charging
def max_charge(model, m):
    return model.e_in[m] <= model.storage_power * interval_freq / 60


model.max_charge = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=max_charge)


# max discharging
def max_discharge(model, m):
    return model.e_out[m] <= model.storage_power * interval_freq / 60


model.max_max_discharge = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=max_discharge)


def soc_update(model, m):
    if m == 0:
        eq = model.soc[m] == \
             (
                     (model.storage_energy * 1) +
                     (model.e_in[m] * model.chargeEff) -
                     (model.e_out[m] / model.dchargeEff)
             )
    else:
        eq = model.soc[m] == \
             (
                     model.soc[m - 1] +
                     (model.e_in[m] * model.chargeEff) -
                     (model.e_out[m] / model.dchargeEff)
             )

    return eq


model.soc_update = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=soc_update)


def soc_min(model, m):
    eq = model.soc[m] >= model.storage_energy * 0.2

    return eq


model.soc_min = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=soc_min)


def soc_max(model, m):
    eq = model.soc[m] <= model.storage_energy * 1

    return eq


model.soc_max = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=soc_max)


def throughput_limit(model):
    energy_sum = sum(model.e_out[idx] for idx in model.m_index)
    return energy_sum <= model.storage_energy * 365


model.throughput_limit = Constraint(rule=throughput_limit)

Solver = SolverFactory('gurobi')
Solver.options['LogFile'] = "gurobiLog"
# Solver.options['MIPGap'] = 0.0
print('\nConnecting to Gurobi Server...')
results = Solver.solve(model)

if (results.solver.status == SolverStatus.ok):
    if (results.solver.termination_condition == TerminationCondition.optimal):
        print("\n\n***Optimal solution found***")
        print('obj returned:', round(value(model.obj), 2))
    else:
        print("\n\n***No optimal solution found***")
        if (results.solver.termination_condition == TerminationCondition.infeasible):
            print("Infeasible solution")
            exit()
else:
    print("\n\n***Solver terminated abnormally***")
    exit()

grid_use = []
solar = []
wind = []
e_in = []
e_out = []
soc = []
lost_load = []
insufficient_dispatch = []
load = []
idx = []

for i in range(len(load_profile)):
    grid_use.append(value(model.grid[i]) * (60 / interval_freq))
    solar.append(value(model.solar_use[i]) * (60 / interval_freq))
    wind.append(value(model.wind_use[i]) * (60 / interval_freq))
    lost_load.append(value(model.lost_load[i]) * (60 / interval_freq))
    e_in.append(value(model.e_in[i]) * (60 / interval_freq))
    e_out.append(value(model.e_out[i]) * (60 / interval_freq))
    soc.append(value(model.soc[i]))
    load.append(value(model.load_profile[i]) * (60 / interval_freq))

time_stamp = pd.date_range('1/1/2022', periods=len(load_profile), freq='15min')
df_out = pd.DataFrame()

# Yearly Dispatch
df_out["Time Stamp"] = time_stamp
df_out["Month"] = time_stamp.month
df_out["Load"] = load
df_out["Solar"] = solar
df_out["Wind"] = wind
df_out["Charge"] = e_in
df_out["Discharge"] = e_out
df_out["SoC"] = np.array(soc)
df_out["Facility Output"] = df_out["Solar"] + df_out["Wind"] + df_out["Discharge"] - df_out["Charge"]
df_out["Shortfall"] = lost_load
df_out["DFR"] = df_out["Facility Output"] / df_out["Load"]

# Monthly Energy Outputs
summary_table = df_out.groupby('Month').sum() / 4
soc_monthly_avg = df_out.groupby('Month').mean()
selected_df = summary_table[['Load', 'Solar', 'Wind', 'Charge', 'Discharge', 'Facility Output']]
selected_df.loc[:, 'SoC'] = soc_monthly_avg['SoC']
selected_df.loc[:, 'Cycles'] = selected_df["Discharge"] / energy
selected_df.loc[:, 'DFR'] = selected_df["Facility Output"] / selected_df["Load"]
selected_df["Excess"] = selected_df.apply(lambda x: (x['Facility Output'] - x['Load']) * excess_revenue_rate if x['Facility Output'] > x['Load'] else 0, axis=1)
selected_df.loc[:, 'Shortfall'] = selected_df.apply(lambda x: DFR * x['Load'] - x['Facility Output'] if x['DFR'] < DFR else 0, axis=1)
selected_df.loc[:, 'Revenue'] = selected_df[['Facility Output', 'Load']].min(axis=1) * PPA
selected_df.loc[:, 'Shortfall Penalty'] = selected_df["Shortfall"] * -shortfall_penalty
selected_df.loc[:, 'Excess Revenue'] = selected_df["Excess"] * excess_revenue_rate
selected_df.loc[:, 'Total '] = selected_df[['Revenue', 'Shortfall Penalty', 'Excess Revenue']].sum(axis=1)
timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%y-%m-%d_%H-%M')
with pd.ExcelWriter('sample output.xlsx') as writer:
    df_out.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='dispatch', index=False)
    selected_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Summy')
```

this is the output from this code:

[image]
These are the post calculations. I have already done these calculations in the last few lines of the code after I got the yearly output. I want to do these calculations in the code itself. As I mentioned above, if the monthly facility output is less than **90% of the Total monthly demand** then only apply the penalty to it. If the same monthly facility output is **greater than the monthly demand profile** then the facility should get the revenue based on **excess_revenue_rate (50% of PPA)**.

```
NOTE: Facility output = Solar + Wind + Battery Discharge - Battery charge
```